# Average NSDictionaries in an NSArray by date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to output to a graph.

I have an array of NSDictionaries. Each of these dictionaries have an NSDate (`objectForKey:@"date"`) and a value (`objectForKey:@"value"`).

What I want to do is average all the results per day and then order it by date, putting in missing days (the results are all from the last 7 days).

Is there any easy way to do this at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this?

```
NSArray* ary = ...;

__block double sum = 0.0;

[ary enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  sum += [[obj objectForKey:@"value"] doubleValue];
}];

double average = sum / [ary count];
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That looks complicated! :p Is there any chance of a quick explanation as to what you're suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't do _all_ of your question. It executes `sum += [[obj objectForKey:@"value"] doubleValue];` on each element of your array and then divides by the number of elements. Since you know the number of "buckets" in advance it should be pretty easy to do this by date rather than for all elements.

Comment: just a quick one... why are you prefixing `double sum = 0.0` with `__block`? Thanks

Comment: It allows you to change the value of sum while in the block. Without it, the block would take a copy of `sum` rather than changing the "real thing."

Comment: oh brilliant. :) Thought it might be something like that. :) Thanks